# Looking for volunteers, resources and/or SIG - RPI image testers

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, all.

My early experiences with ROS have taken me down some bumpy roads, finding obstacles regarding my platform of choice.

(Trying to) develop a robot using a Raspberry PI is a bit of a challenge, even to get the development environment up and running, left alone the robot itself.

Well, long story short, I saw myself forced to create SD images of ROS Hydro, running on Wheezy, but this was done using QEMU and other dirty tricks.

The very first image is about to be ready and I thought that it might be nice to share. My goal is to have Hydro running on Raspbian on a 4 GB image, ready to boot and go.

So, here are the questions:

a) Would you be interested in such an image to start using and eventually report back errors ?  I need more stuff than "it boots" or "it works", as far as feedback goes. Would be really nice to have the details of the robot/application you used this image on.

b) Would there be someone interested in hosting this image, in case we have a big demand ?

c) I will be publishing a wiki-like tutorial of how I did it; In case someone wants to take a look at it and see if it is worth publishing here, I'll be more than glad to offer it.

So, just to be in the same page, this is NOT officially endorsement, but is a nice and practical way of having a working RPI system with ROS with the following:

"Vanilla" Raspbian (Debian Wheezy on Raspberry PI) image, with ROS Hydro installed, on an image to be used on 4 GB SD cards.

KR,

Carlos

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174488/looking-for-volunteers,-resources-and/or-sig---rpi-image-testers/) by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2014-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest that you start a discussion on the [Embedded SIG mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-embedded) There has already been quite a bit of work put into getting ROS running on the Raspberry Pi and most of the people are on that mailing list.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on 2014-06-23**:
Hi Tully. Thanks for the answer. Good to see your answer, especially being one of the admins.

The list you mentioned has 55 questions since its creation, and the latest entry dates from May. I still think this discussion belongs here. If it is all the same to you, I'll keep it active.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-06-23**:
I would suggest at least posting to that mailing list pointing out this question -- there is a good chance that a large portion of that group rarely logs in here, and with so many questions getting posted, they may not even see this one.